# How can i check to see if a specific integer is within array?

Tags: php

Is there a specific way to check for a specific integer within a switch statment.

For example.

```
$user = $ads[$i]->from_user;
```

To check for the number 2 as $i in the above expression.

Comment: Your question title is confusing (after reading the actual question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check like:

```
if ($ads[$i] === 2)
{
 // code here
}
```

Or if you meant alone, you can do:

```
if ($i === 2)
{
 // code here
}
```

If the number in string representation (type), you should use `==` rather than `===`.

If however you meant whether 2 is present in the array `$ads`:

```
if (in_array(2, $ads))
{
 // 2 found in $ads array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you right, what you want is to check if the key`2`exists in`$ads`.

```
if(array_key_exists(2, $ads)) {
    // the key 2 exists in the array
}
```

This way, you should get the result in **constant time O(1)** because`array_key_exists`is implemented with a hashtable lookup.

`in_array`would require **linear time O(n)**.

Comment: Was this what you meant or not?

Answer (score 0):

its simple, better you can use `===` operator to match your values with its datatype